# Devise/Cancan Signout User On Controller Action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cancan

I have implemented Devise for Authentication and Authorization in ROR application everything seems fine but getting one issue.
I have two modals "Account" and "Transactiona" , and so two controllers respectively.

My Transaction Index view call one of Account Controller method like this

```
$.post("accounts/our_miles_balance/?account_number="+$("#account_number").val(),function(data)
{
   $("#our_miles_balance").val(data);
});
```

When this ajax post run it gives following error and sign out admin user

**You need to sign in or sign up before continuing**

Here is my Ability Class

```
class Ability
include CanCan::Ability

def initialize(user)
  user ||= User.new # guest user
  if user.role == 1 #admin
    can :manage, :all
    can :read, :all
  elsif user.role == 2 #Vendor
    can :manage, VendorTransaction
    can :index, Account
  end
end
end
```

What i m doing wrong her, please help....

**Edit**

Ok Here is my Transaction controller

```
require 'csv'
class TransactionsController < ApplicationController
load_and_authorize_resource
helper_method :sort_column, :sort_direction

respond_to :html, :js
def index
  per_page = 40
  @transactions = Transaction.search(params[:id]).order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction)

 respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.csv { render :csv => @transactions}
end
```

AND Account Controller

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController
load_and_authorize_resource
helper_method :sort_column, :sort_direction
def index
   @accounts = Account.search(params[:program_id]
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render :json => @accounts}
 end

 def our_miles_balance
   a = Account.find_by_account_number(params[:account_number])
   @miles = Account.our_miles_balance(a.id) if ?a!=nil
    respond_to do |format|
     format.json { render json: @miles}
  end
end
end
```

Comment: @shingara, i have added controller code, please have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `load_and_authorize_resource`, it's calling `authorize!(:our_miles_balance, @account)` before the `our_miles_balance` controller action. [Documentation.](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/authorizing-controller-actions)

#### Option 1

Add

```
can :our_miles_balance, Account
```

to your ability class.

#### Option 2

In the controller do

```
load_and_authorize_resource :except => :our_miles_balance
```

and in the `our_miles_balance` action do

```
authorize! :read, @account
```

Comment: i used 2nd option, 1st didn't work, with 2nd option getting this error, "No route matches [POST] "/accounts/our_miles_balance", any idea...

Comment: That has nothing to do with CanCan. Your routes/controller is set up incorrectly.

Comment: when there was no devise and cancan added above was working fine, no routing error was coming, after i added this stuff it error out..